# Linux. Время модификации файла

Tags: linux, timestamp

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли в ОС семейства linux получать время последней модификации файла без учёта часового пояса? Чтобы оно не изменялось при просмотре одного и того же файла на разных pc с разными настройками timezones?
Проблема в том, что эта информация учитывается в одной программе расчета хешей и потому цифры нестабильны.

Comment: а перевести его в UTC?

Comment: Не подходит, допустим какой-то файл записан на pc:utc+3, при просмотре его на другом pc, где timezone=utc, время модификации автоматом изменяется(-3). Как нибудь можно принудить linux не делать этого?

Comment: есть время, которое записано в аттрибутах файла, а есть отображаемое. Вы не путаете их?

Comment: Поле st_mtime  структуры функции stat() это атрибут файла? Надеюсь, что не путаю

Comment: да. и если использовать "как есть", то скорее всего там то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Нет, попробую изложить суть иначе, что мне нужно. Есть dos программа, которая расчитывает  хеш сумму на основе содержимого файла и времени модификации, а также некоторых других вещей.Dos никак не преобразует и не интерпретирует это время, походу часовые пояса там отсутствуют в принципе. Стоит задача сделать такую же программу под linux, но как решить проблему со скачащим временем модификации в зависимости от настроенного timezone я пока не понял..

Comment: в линуксе время внутри записывается в utc (если только не сделать по другому). в досе время записывалось локальное по часам (в виндах раньше тоже так было). Если Вы используете UTC, то "скачущие часовые пояса" для Вас не должны быть проблемой.

Comment: А как можно сделать по другому (не utc)?

Comment: используйте функции для перевода в локальное время. localtime(..), но собственно мы этим и введем изначальную Вашу проблему.

Comment: Я боюсь использование utc мне здесь не поможет. Допустим я копирую файл на 2 загрузочные флешки: dos/linux. Загрузочная флешка linux имеет timezone= utc+0. Dos же сохраняет локальное время того pc на котором произошло копирование(timezone может быть любым). В результате время модификации одного и тоже же файла на 2 флешках отличаются:(

Comment: тогда может выбросить это время? проверяйте по хешу содержимого и всех делов.

Comment: Если б все так просто, старое  Dos-ПО трогать не можно, речь как бы шла об унификации-)

Comment: в принципе, никто не гарантирует, что на досовских машинах время везде одинаковое. ntp (как в линуксе) туда вряд ли подвезли. Так что даже на одних дос машинах уже схема не работает по дизайну.